# Last month's last date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, monthcalendar

I have a textbox in which I show only month and year. So when I have June 2013, and when I look for First half, then I want the previous month's date to 14th of June.
So in Javascript I was simply using

```
var currentmonth=doucument.getElementbyId("textbox");
var currentdate="01-"+currentmonth;// as earlier I had 1st to 15 of month.
```

I want to get the last months' last date that too in a format, like

```
"31-May-2013".
```

I am trying to change like:

```
currentdate= new Date(currentdate).get...//but not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create date object:

```
var currentdate = new Date("01-"+currentmonth)
```

Set last day of month using `setFullYear`, `getFullYear` and `getMonth` methods:

```
currentdate.setFullYear(test.getFullYear(), test.getMonth()+1, 0)
```